# Getting Low Res. output video recording even after specifying Max Video Size

Tags: android, android-camera, mediarecorder

I am trying to record video in background.When i use codecs to record the video, it is giving me lowest  output of 176 x 144 even if i specify video size of 1920 x 1080. Below is my code.

```
  mediaRec.setCamera(camera);
  mediaRec.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
  mediaRec.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
  mediaRec.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4_SP);
  mediaRec.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
  mediaRec.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
  mediaRec.setVideoSize(1920,1080);
```

But when i set profile using Camcorder Profile, i am getting High resolution(1080p) Video But it has some jittery frames in starting.So i want to use codecs, but if i use codecs with below code my app throws exception on stopping video Recording.Any idea on where i doing wrong.I have tested this code on Nexus 4 & One plus One.

```
  mediaRec.setCamera(camera);
  mediaRec.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
  mediaRec.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
  mediaRec.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
```

Comment: You cannot specify an arbitrary size in `setVideoSize()`. You need to use one of the sizes returned by [`getSupportedVideoSizes()` on `Camera.Parameters`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedVideoSizes%28%29). "my app throws exception on stopping video Recording" -- use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash.

Comment: Thanks. I already obtained device Supported video size using method you suggested but does it make any difference in video quality if i dont use any Codecs & go with my second code posted above.